# New Transactional sending Email API Error 400: TriggeredSend definition not sendable due to definition status

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send

I've created a new send definition OK with a status 201 : where URL parameter "status" = "Active"... When I check the response I can see that it is set to "New".

When I try to post to "/messaging/v1/email/messages/{generateMessageId}" I get "TriggeredSend definition not sendable due to definition status"

My Definition:

```
 "definitionKey": "Test_001",
    "status": "Active",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "description": "Created via REST",
    "classification": "Default Transactional",
    "content": {
        "customerKey": "xxxx"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "list": "xxxx",
        "dataExtension": "xxxx",
        "autoAddSubscriber": true,
        "updateSubscriber": true
    },
    "options": {
        "trackLinks": true
    }
```

Send request:

```
  "definitionKey": "Test_001",
    "recipient": {
        "contactKey": "xxxx",
        "to": "xxxx",
    }
```

Example response:

```
statusCode: 201 {
    "requestId": "4933d8e0-9d88-4818-8cb2-4af94ab0ec36",
    "name": "Test 2",
    "definitionKey": "Test_002",
    "description": "Created via REST",
    "classification": "Default Transactional",
    "status": "New",
    "createdDate": "2019-05-14T09:55:00",
    "modifiedDate": "2019-05-14T09:55:00",
    "content": { "customerKey": "f0509ac4-9722-4614-8cea-f19f4bafe73d" },
    "subscriptions": { "dataExtension": "858FCE9F-0675-4B31-BB57-034575ED72A0", "list": "All Subscribers ext id", "autoAddSubscriber": true, "updateSubscriber": true },
    "options": { "trackLinks": true }
}
```

Comment: What is the request & route you are sending when you set the status. "New" status tells me its not in "running" or active status

Comment: POST to : xxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/definitions

Comment: and what is the JSON response of the call, I get a 201 created and I see status = Active

Comment: Ive added a response to the description (got 201 actually) but still status = "New"... Any chances for a code sample? @EazyE

Comment: I would make sure your content passes validation in the UI. You might be throwing a validation error is why this isn't going to active status

Comment: The issue was a validation error in my email content (no subject) I was able to send the message OK - @EazyE : Could you post an answer so I can mark one green?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the triggersenddefinition status is not being set to "Active" when specifying "Active" but being set to "New", ensure that there is not a validation issue with the email you are using in the `content` node. The easiest way to validate the email is to do a send preview within Content Builder, and reviewing any errors. Then do a patch call to set the status to "Active"