# Marketing cloud: Create definition(Rest api)

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email-template

I am a newfish to Marketing Cloud, I want to create a send definition to send an email to multiple addresses. Can someone help me?

I can't find much information the message: "MCMS_UTM_Validation_email_does_not_pass_validation"

The test email template in here.

```
<a href=\"%%profile_center_url%%\" alias=\"Update Profile\">Update Profile</a><table cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"600\" ID=\"Table5\" Border=0><tr><td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\" color=\"#444444\">This email was sent by: <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br></font></td></tr></table>
```

Error:

```
{
    "message": "MCMS_UTM_Validation_email_does_not_pass_validation: Content.customerKey: ${xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} contains validation errors.  Unable to activate definition.",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Request:
Post https://${xxx}/messaging/v1/email/definitions

```
{
      "definitionKey": "Test11-Email-Send",
      "name": "Test11-Email-Send",
      "description": "Created via REST",
      "content": {
        "customerKey": "${xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}"
      },
      "subscriptions": {
        "list": "All Subscribers - ${xxxx}",
        "autoAddSubscriber": true,
        "updateSubscriber": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are fields missing on your request. The 'classification' and the 'dataExtension'. Despite the default classification is transactional on the [samples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm) it is explicitly added.

You can find a working sample on this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262360/new-transactional-sending-email-api-error-400-triggeredsend-definition-not-send/262407#262407).